# Copy a column from a table to another table in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, database, replication, sql-server-2008-r2

All of my tables have a `GateCode` column which is used for replication purposes.

I have a table `Configuration` which has a `GateCode` column and all tables primary keys are composite of `GateCode` foreign key and an `ID` which is identical.

My problem is I want to not fill `GateCode` in each table in insertion so this field in each table be filled automatically from `Configuration` table.

What should I do?

I use SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: can you tell me the answer now?

Comment: @marc_s you could describe a strategy to solve the problem, not everything has to be answered with vendor specific code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to fill the `GateCode` column for each table in your database with a value that's stored in your `Configuration` table, when any new row is inserted into any of the tables - right?

The only way I see to do this is to have `INSTEAD OF INSERT` triggers on each table. In that trigger, you would then read out the value from the `Configuration` table, and fill the `GateCode` column the newly inserted rows so that when the actual `INSERT` happens, the value is there and the composite primary key will be filled and `NOT NULL`.